# Dependecy Property Auto update (Datetime with timer)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have the following dependency property that works fine but it does not auto update.
The dependency properties are all properties of the RegistrationButton.cls class.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DuurStilstandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DuurStilstand", typeof(string), typeof(RegistrationButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

.NET Wrapper public property:

```
 public string DuurStilstand
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DuurStilstandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DuurStilstandProperty, value); }
    }
```

What i am basically doing is trying to display a time (DateTime with default 3 min) and after that the time keeps increasing by using a timer and increments the Datetime by 1 second every second.

So on the screen it should display 00:03:00 and starts incrementing every second.

I have tried TwoWay binding (not sure if this is the issue?) but when i try the following my application crashes:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DuurStilstandProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("DuurStilstand", typeof(string), typeof(RegistrationButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

The code that involved creating the button (where the time is being displayed) and the timer:

```
public void InitializeDispatcherTimerStilstand()
    {
        timerStilstand = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerStilstand.Tick += new EventHandler(timerStilstand_Tick);
        timerStilstand.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timerStilstand.Start();
        timerStilstand.ToString();
    }

    private void timerStilstand_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn.AddSeconds(1);
    }
```

Code that creates the button:

**Btn.Duurstilstand** is the property that holds the time (hh:mm:ss format).

```
tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 3, 0); 

        RegistrationButton btn = new RegistrationButton(GlobalObservableCollection.regBtns.Count.ToString());
        btn.RegistrationCount = GlobalObservableCollection.regBtnCount;
        btn.Title = "btnRegistration" + GlobalObservableCollection.regBtnCount;
        btn.BeginStilstand = btn.Time;
        btn.DuurStilstand = String.Format("{0:T}", this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn);

        GlobalObservableCollection.regBtns.Add(btn);
        GlobalObservableCollection.regBtnCount++;

        InitializeDispatcherTimerStilstand();
```

Currently it only seems to display 00:03:00 as time but it does not update when my program is running.

I also tried setting the UpDateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged but it made no difference (this is located in a Style of type RegistrationButton).

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbDuurStilstand" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Text="{Binding DuurStilstand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Margin="7.5,5,0,0" Height="24.8266666666667"/>
```

**EDIT**

```
public void CreateRegistrationButton()
    {
        tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 3, 0); 

        RegistrationButton btn = new RegistrationButton(GlobalObservableCollection.regBtns.Count.ToString());
        btn.RegistrationCount = GlobalObservableCollection.regBtnCount;
        btn.Title = "btnRegistration" + GlobalObservableCollection.regBtnCount;
        btn.BeginStilstand = btn.Time;
        //btn.DuurStilstand = String.Format("{0:T}", this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn);

        GlobalObservableCollection.regBtns.Add(btn);
        GlobalObservableCollection.regBtnCount++;

        InitializeDispatcherTimerStilstand(btn);     
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
timerStilstand.Tick += () => timerStilstand_Tick(btn); //error at ()
```

"Delegate 'System.EventHandler' does not take 0 arguments"

Kind Regards.

Comment: Where did you the change to happen?  `timerStilstand.ToString();` does totally nothing, remove it.

Comment: Could it be i have to access my dependency property in the timer_tick event? If so how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime is an **immutable struct**. You have to catch the result.
I think you need:

```
private void timerStilstand_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn = 
        this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn.AddSeconds(1);

    btn.DuurStilstand = 
        String.Format("{0:T}", this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn);

}
```

---

#### Take 2

```
public void InitializeDispatcherTimerStilstand(RegistrationButton btn)
{
    timerStilstand = new DispatcherTimer();
    //timerStilstand.Tick += new EventHandler(timerStilstand_Tick);
    timerStilstand.Tick += (aa, bb) => timerStilstand_Tick(btn);   // use capturing to pass btn

    timerStilstand.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timerStilstand.Start();
    //timerStilstand.ToString();
}

private void timerStilstand_Tick(RegistrationButton btn)
{
   this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn = 
        this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn.AddSeconds(1);

    btn.DuurStilstand = 
        String.Format("{0:T}", this.tijdStilStandRegistrationBtn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, sadly this does not fix my issue. The time remains at 0.03.00

Comment: You also need to update the DuurStilstand from the Tick event.

Comment: How exactly do i access the Property from within the Tick Event? Ive tried passing a reference with the timer but i cannot seem to access the RegistrationButton property DuurStilStand. Thanks

Comment: @Rakr - added a line, assuming `btn` is accessible. Otherwise make it a field.

Comment: Its not accessible. I edit my code with the method where the button gets created. There can be multiple buttons so i have to set the property of that button. Even if i pass a reference to the Timer method i cannot seem to access it in the Tick method. Thanks

Comment: My last edit should do the trick, although it still leaves the issue of managing the timer(s) themselves...  Maybe use 1 fixed timer and a fixed list of 'active' buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Although i am getting a error "Delegate 'System.EventHandler does not take 0 arguements' at the () (made a edit). I am afraid i am not to familiar with Delegates since i never use them. Regards.

Comment: Okay many thanks Henk! Although i have no idea how that line works with the delegate.